# Manga wherein the main character gets a wolf tail

Tags: story-identification, manga

I don't recall much about it, but I remembered reading a Japanese manga wherein the main character is a high school guy who somehow ends up getting a wolf's tail. Furthermore, his male friend also ends up with an animal characteristic, namely bird wings, and became a villain for a few chapters.

And that's all that I can remember... oh, and some sort of chain that, if I'm not mistaken, makes him stronger or something. I've read it through an application called Manga Rock, but it can no longer be accessed now.

Any clues as to which manga closely resembles this?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Almost certainly [Kami to Sengoku Seitokai](https://myanimelist.net/manga/1923/Kami_to_Sengoku_Seitokai) (Student Council God War):

> The "Unsinkable" Katsuragi Musashi is attending his 1st day at school, a month into the semester. He's called that because through a series of lucky incidents he has never lost a fight. Not 5 minutes into his 1st day, he's drawn into a fight to save an old friend, Kaoru. After taking down 2 guys in one shot, he is saved from taking on 6 more when the vice president of the student council and resident idol, Kagura Mami, shows up and stops it from going any further. Which is strange in and of itself since she never helps anyone. Later on, while running from his childhood friend, Akane, Katsuragi stumbles across an old school building with a mysterious large door inside, that cannot be opened. The opening of the door, this one event would change his life and effect those around him. Now suddenly, he's being named successor to the student council president by Kagura, who is now living with him and chosen students, himself included, are imbued with supernatural powers akin to animals. Also, **Katsuragi now has a tail**.

The cover art shows him with a chain.

See also a [description on the MAL forums](https://myanimelist.net/forum/?topicid=303073&show=0) by someone else who was trying to remember this manga.

Comment: Excellent work! I am curious as to how you found it. I failed at my own searches.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I found the forum post with `manga "wolf tail" site:myanimelist.net`

Comment: Ah, cool. Thank you.